# I´m getting Request processing failed with spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I´m doing a simple form using `spring` that will later connect with an ejb.

so my jsp is (i got the spring libraries in my jsp):

```
<form:form commandName="TestDTO" method="POST">
    <form:input path="test" maxlength="20"
            id="test" />
    <input type="button"
        onClick="javascript:validarCamposConsulta('consultaTest.htm')"
        value="Consultar" class="boton" />
</form:form>
```

My controller goes like this (i´ve my spring imports after the package declaration):

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
private final String testDTO = "TestDTO";

@RequestMapping("/consulta.htm")
public ModelAndView preload(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String forward = "/consulta/CONSULTA"; 

    /*try {
        configuradorIDA.setupIsbanDataAccess();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("Error al inicializar IDA: " + e.getMessage());
    }*/
    return new ModelAndView(forward);
}

@RequestMapping("/consultaTest.htm")
public final String consultaTest(
        @ModelAttribute(testDTO)
        final TestDTO testdto,
        final BindingResult result,
        final ModelMap model,
        final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response) {
    String forward = "/consulta/CONSULTA";
    testdto.getTest();
    model.addAttribute(testDTO, testdto);
    return forward;
}

}
```

I´m running it on websphere 7 so when i run it i get the next error:

```
    Error 500: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: 
Request processing failed; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object 
for bean name 'TestDTO' available as request attribute
```

Does anyone knows what´s happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok it seems that my methods preload firm should be

```
@RequestMapping("/consulta.htm")
    public ModelAndView preload(@ModelAttribute(testDTO)
    final TestDTO testdto, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
```

and that solved it.